# How to add more href elements for each column in the chart with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

What I am doing here is add a link for each column but it works only with the first **`link1`'s column**.

Please help me to correct this problem and make my code shorter when there are **not only 3 `links`** for each `Plant`.

```
    ['Year', 'link1', 'Dollars', 'link2', 'Conts', 'link3', 'Quantity'],
    ['Plant 1', 'http://google.com', 1000, 'http://bing.com', 400, 'http://alexa/com', 2000],
    ['Tan Thanh', 'http://dell.com', 1170, 'http://lenovo.com', 460, 'http://hp.com', 1420],
    ['Plant 3', 'http://w3schools.com', 660, 'http://microsoft.com', 1120, 'http://adobe.com', 1080],
    ['Plant 4', 'http://apple.com', 1030, 'http://htc.com', 540, 'http://samsung.com', 2240]
```

## **Summary:**

**In Plant 1:**

*Problem goes here:*

- Click on the first column (blue column), a new tab appears with
  `http://google.com`.
- Click on the second column (red column), a new tab appears with
  `http://google.com`.
- Click on the third column (yellow column), a new tab appears with
  `http://google.com`.

*It must be:*

- Click on the first column (blue column), a new tab appears with
  `http://google.com`.
- Click on the second column (red column), a new tab appears with
  `http://bing.com`.
- Click on the third column (yellow column), a new tab appears with
  `http://alexa/com`.

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JASWb/1/)**

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 550px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'link1', 'Dollars', 'link2', 'Conts', 'link3', 'Quantity'],
        ['Plant 1', 'http://google.com', 1000, 'http://bing.com', 400, 'http://alexa/com', 2000],
        ['Tan Thanh', 'http://dell.com', 1170, 'http://lenovo.com', 460, 'http://hp.com', 1420],
        ['Plant 3', 'http://w3schools.com', 660, 'http://microsoft.com', 1120, 'http://adobe.com', 1080],
        ['Plant 4', 'http://apple.com', 1030, 'http://htc.com', 540, 'http://samsung.com', 2240]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 2, 4, 6]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(view, options);
    function selectHandler1() {
        window.open(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1), '_blank');
    }

    function selectHandler2() {
        window.open(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 3), '_blank');
    }

    function selectHandler3() {
        window.open(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 5), '_blank');
    }
    // Add our selection handler.
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler1);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler2);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single event handler, and fetch the relevant URL based on the column index of the selected element:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    // test selection array length, since it can be 0 if the user deselects an element
    if (selection.length) {
        var row = selection[0].row;
        // convert the view column index to the table column index,
        // then subtract 1 to get the URL index
        var urlCol = view.getTableColumnIndex(selection[0].column) - 1;
        window.open(data.getValue(row, urlCol), '_blank');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's great. However, it doesn't seem to work in the right way as the `first` and the `third` column. Your code works well with the `second` column as the updated JSFILLDE **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/JASWb/2/**

Comment: Sorry, you have to convert from the view's column index to the DataTable's column index: `var urlCol = view.getTableColumnIndex(selection[0].column) - 1;`.  Answer updated.